# How do I call OpenGL methods that require pointers in C#?

Tags: opengl, c#, c++, opentk

I have found the following C++ code in [this](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/hellotriangle.html) tutorial to draw a triangle with OpenGL 4:

```
float points[] = {
   0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,
   0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,
  -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f
};
GLuint vbo = 0;
glGenBuffers (1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9 * sizeof (float), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

I use C# and OpenTK, so I tried to translate the code:

```
        float[] points = 
        {
           0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,
           0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,
          -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f
        };
        uint[] vbo = {0};
        GL.GenBuffers(1, vbo);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo[0]);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 9 * sizeof(float), ppoints, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
```

The problem is that `GL.GenBuffers()` and `GL.BufferData()` require pointers (Visual Studio shows `*int` or `out int` and `ref float*`, `IntPtr`).

I've tried to fix this, but it didn't work:

```
        float[] points = 
        {
           0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,
           0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,
          -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f
        };
        uint[] vbo = {0};
        GL.GenBuffers(1, vbo);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo[0]);

        unsafe
        {
            fixed (float* ppoints = points)
            {
                GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 9 * sizeof(float), ppoints, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
            }
        }
```

So my question is how to use these methods in a good C# style?

Comment: Have you tried simply adding the out and ref to the parameters in the function call (don't see you mentioning that in your question)?

Comment: Don't allocate a whole array just to return a single value! See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
    var points = new float[] 
    {
       0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,
       0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,
      -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f
    };
    int vbo = GL.GenBuffer();
    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);        
    GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, points.Length * sizeof(float), points, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
```

OpenTK provides three overloads for each method with *typed* pointers. For example:

```
const GLfloat* -> ref float, float[], float* (input)
      GLfloat* -> out float, float[], float* (output)
```

1. Use `ref/out float` if you wish to pass/retrieve a single item.
2. Use `float[]` if you wish to pass/retrieve an array of items.
3. Use `float*` when writing unsafe code (e.g. a pointer to unmanaged memory or the stack).

*Untyped* pointers get the same overloads using generics:

```
const GLvoid* -> ref T, T[], IntPtr (input)
      GLvoid* -> out T, T[], IntPtr (output)
```

Starting with OpenTK 1.1, `Gen*` and `Delete*` methods get one additional overload, to simplify usage from F# (and similar functional languages). This is often the optimal approach:

```
int buffer = GL.GenBuffer();
```

Which is equivalent to the more verbose:

```
int buffer;
GL.GenBuffers(1, out buffer);
```

Note that unsigned types get both unsigned and signed overloads. For example, `GLuint` gets both `uint` and `int` overloads. The reason is that unsigned integers are not [CLS-Compliant][1] and cannot be used by all .Net languages (e.g. VB.Net). This is something to keep in mind if you are writing a public API to be consumed outside of C#.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Good explanations! But unfortunately this line does not work:

`GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, points.Length * sizeof(float), points, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);`

I think it is, because `points.Length * sizeof(float)` is not an IntPtr !?

Comment: It works on opentk/develop (version 1.1.5+). For previous versions you need to use `new IntPtr(...)`.

Comment: OK, but where can I download the develop version? I only find the stable release.

Comment: You can download the latest code from [github](https://github.com/opentk/opentk). Simply double-click OpenTK.sln and build in release mode. v1.1.5 will be released this week.

Comment: In the Version.txt stand 1.1.1741.0, not 1.1.5? I have downloaded the ZIP from the link above.

Comment: This should be OK.  1.1.5 is the human readable name (meaning sixth release of the 1.1 API ). Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, but after I exchanged the dll the same line give again an error.

Comment: It would help if you could post the exact error message.

Comment: This works: `GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, new IntPtr(points.Length * sizeof(float)), points, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);` But you said that works with the newest version of OpenTK like this: `GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, points.Length * sizeof(float), points, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);`But it says that the method has invalid arguments. I think I haven't the newest OpenTK.dll, although I have download the code from github and compiled it. Can I download the newest OpenTK.dll anywhere direkt?